# a function inside an aggregate function in a pivot block cause the error ORA-22806: not an object or REF

Tags: oracle

This code works perfectly fine

```
with 
function do_something(arg integer) return integer
is 
begin
    return f(arg);
end;
t  as (SELECT 1 a FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM t PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(do_something(a)) FOR a IN (1, 2));
```

But this code doesn't

```
WITH 
function do_something(arg varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
    return 'fff';
end;
t (a) AS (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM sys.odcivarchar2list ('a', 'b', 'd'))
SELECT *
  FROM t PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(do_something(a)) FOR a IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
```

> [Error] Execution (42: 27): ORA-22806: not an object or REF

I have no clues why it happens

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d14cfe4f5e69942d4cf92950c86e8c4a)

Comment: You have a typo in the first query as you have two `IS` keywords.

Answer (score 2):

It is something to do with the `t` subquery factoring clause and nothing to do with the `PIVOT` or the function.

If you do:

```sql
WITH 
function do_something(arg varchar2) return varchar2
is
begin
    return 'fff';
end;
t (a) AS (
  SELECT 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   t
PIVOT (
  ANY_VALUE(do_something(a))
  FOR a IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);
```

Then the code works and outputs:

> | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | fff | fff | *null* | fff |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=145a0cdf0890f1e7437e4b87548fc327)*